# Can I use an undamaged US immigration visa from a passport with a very slightly water damaged cover page photo?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports

I realize that I should replace my passport in the case of a slightly water marked ID-page (the top left 1/5 of the picture has slight discoleration). I have just been issued my US immigration visa as a separate page in my passport. If I get a new passport, can I still use the immigration visa from my old passport? (The visa page is 100% intact with no water damage).

Comment: Does "cover page" refer to the cover or to the page with the identification data?  If the latter, I would suggest using the term "ID page" or "data page" or something like that.  Also, are you planning to use the visa in combination with another passport?  If the water damage is too slight to require replacing the passport then there's no reason to think it would affect the validity of the undamaged visa.

Comment: Oh, that's true. It is actually the ID page. Basically from this site (https://jp.usembassy.gov/visas/faq-list/general-questions-niv/) I read that "If the photo page on your passport has been damaged [...], please apply for a new visa in a new passport, submitting both the damaged and new passport in support of your application." (this is referring to non-immigration visas though).  I've also read cases where watermarks on the ID page have resulted in denial of entry.

Comment: @TomasBy Whilst this is true for an expired/replaced passport, it's not necessarily true for a damaged one. It depends on the amount of damage, and can be at the discretion of airline/immigration staff.

Comment: I see. So in theory, if I get a new passport and my old one is canceled, if the old passport with the visa is heavily damaged (even with an intact visa) then even the visa there might not be accepted with a new passport. Seeing how the extent of the damage is a 2mm lightened blur at the top of my forehead, I would think I would be safe to assume that this does not fall into the heavily damaged category. I guess at the end of the day then it's really up to the discretion of the staff.

Comment: If it was not enough damage for the consular staff to notice and comment on it, it is unlikely to be a problem. I would just go straight to the US, apply for the physical green card, and maybe replace the passport later.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's good advice, but it does assume that the damage didn't occur after the visa was placed in the passport.

Comment: These cases of water damage leading to denied entry: did they concern denial of entry into the US?  I get the sense that some countries are far more sensitive to damage than is the US.  Is there any chance to ask the US consulate whether they find the damage significant?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the damage happened after retrieving the visa so we don't what the typical response will be. @phoog thats a good point. A lot of the things I read about denial of entry are generally sensational headlines to countries other than the US.